# How to handle Table joins in microservices

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am new to the microservices architecture, i have a scenario as follows

```
Database1 - tbl_users (userid | user_name)

Users Api - returns all users in the table tbl_users

Database2 - tbl_orders (Orderid | order_name | user_id (FK))

Orders Api - returns all orders in the table tbl_orders
```

in a monolithic approach i would do a join in the orders api and display the users that have made the orders, but in a microservice approach, how do i handle such a  case when i have to display the users and orders in one view from the orders api? taking into consideration i am new to this

Comment: It's a misconception that "micro" means that everything has to be broken down to the lowest possible level, even when a task is not conveniently implemented by doing that. This can lead to grossly inefficient designs where you pretend your database doesn't exist and can't handle joins. "Gather combined data for this user/these users and their orders" can be "micro" enough for a service. Pretending there is no relationship between users and orders will not *actually* make microservices for users and orders independent.

Comment: Thank you @JeroenMostert, but consider its a booking application, where i have tables like state, country, location, in a microservice. and i have orders in another, just as stated above, and i have to join those tables to orders, would it be wise if i move the orders table to the database housing country, states, location, users etc) then that removes the microservice concept, or whats your take in such

Comment: There "ain't no rule" that you cannot have a microservice that only gives back data on orders, and a microservice that gives you back data on users, and *another* that gives you back data on the both of them combined. But in most systems this would not be an advantage because any actual change to the system would likely mean all these services must be updated in concert, and allowing services to be updated independently is exactly one of the reasons why microservices exist in the first place. Be careful to separate the intended *purpose* of microservices from their *implementations*.

Comment: I elaborated in my answer, but I agree wholeheartedly with @JeroenMostert. There's a horrible trend of calling databases exposed over HTTP micro-services. This combined with people being afraid of 'monoliths' is turning solution design into a nightmare at times. A well-designed monolith with clear boundaries encouraged and enforced in the code can be a thing of beauty.

Answer (score 1):

Such cases are usually handled by either a compositional service sitting in between the UI concerns and the dedicated services. This compositional service will response to a query from the UI, aggregate the data from various services in order to build a full view model and then send it back to the UI.

This service can take various forms, and it can be either a client-side composition or a server-side composition. An example of client-side composition is a SPA where a component will fetch from multiple APIs, project the data into something useful and render it, while a server side example could be the controller serving a view. I used the term "service" loosely here, but the idea is quite general.

To look at it another way, remove all notions of hosted APIs or even the knowledge of databases. If you had to integrate two different libraries in code, what would the compositional function look like? It would call one thing, do some stuff, call the second thing, do some more stuff, return the results.

Hosted APIs etc just add implementation details and complexity, but the principle stays the same.

You raised some concerns about the performance impact of having to coordinate multiple calls to different services, and this is certainly valid. Not only performance, but transient error handling and transactional integrity become vastly more complex when dealing with API calls instead of joining at the database level.

Some questions to ask yourself:
1. How recent does my data have to be? Can you accept a cached version of the user, and do you want to maintain and invalidate that cache in your application?
2. Are there read-optimised versions of the API that already do some of the data-transformations for you, and maintain an aggressive cache on their end?
3. Are my boundaries around my components drawn correctly, or should I merge or slice up the services in a different way so that data that relates to one another lives close enough that latency does not become a bottleneck?
4. Are there different types of data storage strategies that can be applied to those components that are queried often so they start broadcasting data changes, which then enables you to build read-optimised data stores of your own (think event sourcing, pub-sub, that kind of thing)

Comment: Thank you @Yannick for your reply, i was considering performance, because if i have about 4, 5 service which i want to join to the orders service (i.e state, country, city etc). the over head time of calling five services in a composite service, would be much thereby affecting performance.

Comment: Performance is always a concern when dealing with multiple services, and it's one of the prices you have to pay. It's a bug bear of mine when people always want to split every damn thing up into micro-services 'just cuz'. I'll edit my answer with some more detail about performance impacts.

Comment: Would catching the response of the user api in the order service be an OK route to take?

Answer (score 0):

Yo can check [this article](https://maltronblog.wordpress.com/2015/02/15/fkrelation/) that gives some examples and explain detailed.

[image]

> "This radically approach brings us a one concerning question:
>
> With an old approach, a simple SQL join will bring us both the
>   customer and deal information. Now, we need to call two SQL in order
>   to get the same result. Is the new approach slower because we need to
>   make two SQL calls to gather same information ? The answer: YES.
>
> However, the benefits in turning those entities into services are:
>
> - The Deal table can be in different databases (or schemas) without
>     impacting a single database when scale out kicks in.
> - Maintenance in
>     each service will done easily, once each table doesn’t relate to
>     anything else.
> - You may (if makes sense in your project) use different
>     persistence technologies (such as NoSQL).
>
> Keeping things loosely
>   couple and high cohesive is not as simple and many argue.  The whole
>   idea of is to set the boundaries within our problem domain and ensure
>   that the related behavior is in one place and communicates with other
>   boundaries as loosely as possible."

Comment: Would you please explain how NoSQL can be useful if we are operating on references? Another approach would be to store complete information instead of reference ids but in near future any of those details might get updated in original database. Then all older records will have non updated data.